# Internet Explorer 11 Timeline Year View on remote desktop session displays dates with longdatestring

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

On Internet Explorer 11 on the remote desktop session at the company I work for the dates display in long format - stretching the days and the events.

This issue only occurs on Internet Explorer 11 and not on any other browser on the remote desktop session, such as Chrome.

If I use Internet Explorer 11 off the remote desktop session this issue does not occur. I was just wondering if this issue has happened before and if anyone has any solutions or ideas about how to resolve it.

Thanks.

Comment: fullCalendar is supposed to support IE11 - see https://fullcalendar.io/getting-help (at the bottom). But it's unclear specifically what you mean by "long format". Can you please show a) your calendar setup code and b) comparative screenshots of the fault in IE, and the working version in another browser, so we can see exactly what is happening. Also please state which version of fullCalendar you are using. Thanks.

Comment: P.S. If this only occurs on one particular machine, it could potentially be something to do with the default date display settings in windows. I'm not sure if the browser would pick up on those and use them as default formatting for a JavaScript date, but it sounds a bit suspicious if it its only a single machine affected. Another thing might be to check and ensure that IE is not running the calendar page in compatibility mode or anything silly like that.

Comment: The version being used is 4.3.0. I am unable to post screenshots as this is a new account and I don't have enough reputation yet. However, I have posted the screenshots of what is happening and setup code here - https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/5037

Comment: For future reference you can post screenshots on imgur and then post links to them on here. Glad you fixed it, although it's still pretty weird that it only occurred on one instance of I.E.

Answer (score 1):

After some digging around in the documentation I found you can set the date format for each slot in your timeline view by using **slotLabelFormat** on initialisation of the calendar - https://fullcalendar.io/docs/slotLabelFormat